# executing single query in loop increase time every time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Am executing one query which is the same as below. Now here the problem is as limit increasing its increasing execution of time.

I am adding limit using a PHP script. So anyone likes to suggest to stop increasing the time of execution by mysql?

There is total records are 12042993 which I have to copy from one table to another table. But when am executing the single query without limit that time it's not working.

So will you please suggest a better way to avoid this increasing time?

For now, I have added one index which is below. I know its wrong. But for me, I just have to concentrate only and only on this query. There is no any other query is running on the entire server/database.

```
alter table cdrs add index cdrs_data  (`callstart`,`uniqueid`,`accountid`,
    `type`,`callerid`,`sip_from_uri`,`callednum`,`billseconds`,trunk_id,disposition,
    debit,cost,provider_id,pricelist_id, package_id,pattern,notes,reseller_id,
    provider_call_cost, call_direction,calltype,progress_media_stamp,
    progress_mediamsec, is_recording,call_reward_amount);

insert into cdrs_data(uniqueid,accountid,type,callerid,sip_from_uri,callednum,
    billseconds,trunk_id,disposition,callstart,debit,cost,provider_id,pricelist_id,
    package_id,pattern,notes,reseller_id,provider_call_cost,call_direction,
    calltype,progress_media_stamp,progress_mediamsec,is_recording,call_reward_amount)
  select  uniqueid,accountid,type,callerid, sip_from_uri, callednum,billseconds,
       trunk_id,disposition, callstart,debit,cost, provider_id,pricelist_id,package_id,
       pattern,notes,reseller_id,provider_call_cost, call_direction,calltype,
       progress_media_stamp,progress_mediamsec, is_recording,call_reward_amount 
    from callinfo 
    where callstart >= '2017-01-30 00:00:00' and callstart < '2019-05-06 00:00:00' 
    order by callstart asc limit 24000,3000
```

All suggestions are appriciated.

Comment: Why are you using a PHP script? When you say doing it as a single query without LIMIT didn’t work, what do you mean? We’re you executing that from PHP? Execute the query without LIMIT from the MySQL command line - be patient, leave it until it finishes. Let us know if that errors. PHP scripts have a timeout that you have probably hit

Comment: Why are you having an index? You do not need it, adding it after loading all the records does speed up the loading of the records.

Answer (score 0):

What percentage of the 12M rows are you transferring?

This gets slower and slower as you increase the `OFFSET`:

```
limit 24000,3000
```

Instead, "remember where you left off".  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Is there an index on `callstart`?

The `INDEX` `cdrs_data` is a terribly long index.  The only way it might be useful is if it is "covering".

The `TABLE` `cdrs_data` -- does it have any indexes?  Of so, disabling the indexes before starting the inserts is likely to speed things up.  Reenable afterward.

Another option is to use mysqldump with a `--where` clause. for the dump side; then `mysql` for loading in the new place.